# Creating a Table of Contents (TOC) on Github: Is there a way I can get rid of the bullet points so I can have a cleaner TOC?

Tags: html, css, github, markdown, tableofcontents

Whenever I try it, even when using HTML and CSS with `list-style-type: none`, I just can't seem to get rid of the bullet points.

The farthest I managed to get was adding a `<style>` element, which does work but Github doesn't parse the HTML completely and the `<style>` element also appears as pure text, which is not the behavior I get on VS Code.

```html
<style>
  #TOC ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
</style>

<div id="TOC">
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

The text `<style> #TOC ul { list-style-type: none; } </style>` will appear right before the real TOC after rendering.

Comment: GitHub documents their Markup processing [here](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup). Note that step two (after the Markdown is converted to HTML in step one) sanitizes the HTML by "aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as script tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes." In other words, GitHub intentionally makes if impossible to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Maybe that's what they intended, but there are workarounds apparently, like the one I mentioned below, which I stumbled upon after many attempts. It does work, and you can see the effects [here](https://github.com/marcglasberg/fast_immutable_collections) for example.

Comment: And I don't know if that's what you meant by the comment, but knowing that it isn't possible is also a contribution to an overall answer, which I would upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [@Waylan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866026/waylan)'s comment: GitHub documents their Markup processing [here](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup). Note that step two — after the Markdown is converted to HTML in step one — sanitizes the HTML by:

> (...) aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as script tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes.

That means Github intentionally doesn't want to the user to create custom styles, so, in theory, you can't really do what you ask. However, in practice, you can still leverage Github's CSS through:

```html
<div id="user-content-toc">
  <ul>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like in practice in the end — you can check out an example [here](https://github.com/FanaroEngineering/fanaro.io):

[image: Proper Github Table of Contents]

Keep in mind that this will surely not be ideal. Because Github might change the `id` at any point in time, which would break your styling. Nevertheless, in the case `id` disappears, at the worst, things will default to `<ul>` — which is not as bad as the case where they completely distort the `<ul>`'s behavior, so watch out!

> I've converted this whole ordeal into a [post](https://fanaro.io/articles/github_toc_hack/github_toc_hack.html) on my website, [fanaro.io](https://fanaro.io).